# Derivative of a fraction

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to derivate:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{3}}{x^3}$$

I apply the table formula:

$$Dx\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f′(x)g(x)−f(x)g′(x)}{g(x)^2}$$

But i always get a wrong result.
My result is:
$$\frac{(2x*x^3)-[(x^2-\frac{1}{3})*3x^2]}{x^9}$$
Which is different from wolfram or geogebra $$\frac{-x^2+1}{x^4}$$
 Where is my error?

Comment: Note that $(x^3)^2=x^6$

Comment: Try simplifying.

Comment: I think you have it, you just cubed the denominator instead of squaring it.

Comment: Also, not sure if you are practicing or what, but a simpler way to do it would be to split it into $x^{-1}-\frac{1}{3}x^{-3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error has been pointed out in the comments.  Here is another way to proceed.  Instead of using the quotient rule you can do some manipulation and then use the power rule, note that :

$$\frac{x^2-\frac{1}{3}}{x^3} = \frac{x^2}{x^3} - \frac{1}{3x^3}$$ so $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{3x^3}$$  So using the power rule we have $$f'(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^4}$$ combining the fractions gives $$f'(x) = \frac{-x^2+1}{x^4}.$$  The first manipulation is really useful in classic integration and differentiation problems and pays to remember.